# WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR BSOD - what is wrong?

Tags: windows-8, bsod

Hello I have a problem with my PC getting the WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR bsod. It is a few months old pc. I am not overclocking or changing anything in bios, but sometimes (this is my third time) I get this bsod out of nowhere. This last time I was just watching some stream on twitch when the pc suddenly crashed.

I have everything up to date in windows update and every other driver as well. 
Everything in Open hardware Monitor seems ok. Right now as of 10 min after the crash, the CPU temp is at 38°C, fans are at 1400RPM

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro 64b.
Here are my spec:

Intel i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz,
Kingston HyperX 8GB DDR3 1600 XMP,
GeForce GTX 660 with 340.52 drivers,
Corsair VS450 power supply,
Gigabyte GA-H87-HD3

you can see the BSOD dump here: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/88i1q2nnqnpzux1/082514-29656-01.dmp?dl=0

Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: You realize that you can really have hardware errors eventhough the system is only a few months old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a L2 Cache error (`GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR`):

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffe001c0287028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000be000000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 000000000100110a, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------


BUGCHECK_STR:  0x124_GenuineIntel

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  chrome.exe

STACK_TEXT:  
nt!KeBugCheckEx
hal!HalBugCheckSystem
nt!WheaReportHwError
hal!HalpMcaReportError
hal!HalpMceHandlerCore
hal!HalpMceHandler
hal!HalpMceHandlerWithRendezvous
hal!HalHandleMcheck
nt!KxMcheckAbort
nt!KiMcheckAbort
0x0


FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x124_GenuineIntel_PROCESSOR_CACHE


===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffe001c0287028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01cfba1500bc1a0e
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 8/25/2014 0:47:19 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe001c02870a8
Section       @ ffffe001c0287180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Generic
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 2
CPU Version   : 0x00000000000306c3
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000004

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe001c02870f0
Section       @ ffffe001c0287240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000004
CPU Id        : c3 06 03 00 00 08 10 04 - ff fb fa 7f ff fb eb bf
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffe001c0287240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffe001c0287138
Section       @ ffffe001c02872c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : GCACHEL2_ERR_ERR (Proc 2 Bank 5)
  Status      : 0xbe0000000100110a
  Address     : 0x0000000010d0a400
  Misc.       : 0x0000015086000086

2: kd> !sysinfo cpuinfo
[CPU Information]
~MHz = REG_DWORD 3193
Component Information = REG_BINARY 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Configuration Data = REG_FULL_RESOURCE_DESCRIPTOR ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,ff,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Identifier = REG_SZ Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3
ProcessorNameString = REG_SZ Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz
Update Status = REG_DWORD 6
VendorIdentifier = REG_SZ GenuineIntel
MSR8B = REG_QWORD 900000000
2: kd> !sysinfo cpuspeed
CPUID:        "Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4570 CPU @ 3.20GHz"
MaxSpeed:     3200
CurrentSpeed: 3193
2: kd> !sysinfo machineid
Machine ID Information [From Smbios 2.7, DMIVersion 39, Size=3050]
BiosMajorRelease = 4
BiosMinorRelease = 6
BiosVendor = American Megatrends Inc.
BiosVersion = F3
BiosReleaseDate = 05/09/2013
SystemManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
SystemProductName = H87-HD3
SystemFamily = To be filled by O.E.M.
SystemVersion = To be filled by O.E.M.
SystemSKU = To be filled by O.E.M.
BaseBoardManufacturer = Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
BaseBoardProduct = H87-HD3
BaseBoardVersion = x.x
```

The BIOS/UEFI is a bit old. The [i5 4xxx is only supported since Version F8](http://www.gigabyte.de/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4516#bios):

> Support New 4th Generation Intel Core Processors

Try to update the BIOS/UEFI and look if this fixes it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have just updated my bios to F8, so I will keep an eye on the crashes and tell you if it worked or not :)

Comment: is your system stable now?

Comment: I haven't had any problems yet. The problem is, that the BSOD I had happened once or twice in a month, so I don't immediately know if it worked, but so far so good, so I will mark your response as solved :)